# Scala compilation error Vert.x response future

Tags: java, scala, vert.x, vertx-eventbus

I'm trying to replicate a code from https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/scala/#_the_event_bus_api but I got a compile error.

```
override def start(): Unit = {
    vertx.eventBus.sendFuture("anAddress", "message 1").onComplete {
      case Success(result) => {
        println("The handler un-registration has reached all nodes")
      }
      case Failure(cause) => {
        println(s"$cause")
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm getting this error:

```
missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: scala.util.Try[io.vertx.scala.core.eventbus.Message[?]] => ?
    vertx.eventBus.sendFuture("anAddress", "message 1").onComplete {
                                                                   ^
```

How can I solve this?

I'm using Scala 2.12.8 and Vert.x 3.7.1

I have looked around but no sucess.

Thanks to advance!

Comment: What version of Scala? What version of vert.x?

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to mention it. It's Scala 2.12.8 and Vert.x 3.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to solve this:

So `vertx.eventBus.sendFuture` returns a `Future[Message[T]`.
`Future`'s `onComplete` method takes a single parameter which is a funciton `f: (Try[T]) => U`.

What you're doing there is you're using an anonymous function for which argument types must be fully declared.

You need to specify the signature of your `f` signature.

Two options I guess:

1)

```
vertx.eventBus.sendFuture("anAddress", "message 1").onComplete { x: Try[Message[_]] =>
  x match {
    case Success(result) => {
      println("The handler un-registration has reached all nodes")
    }
    case Failure(cause) => {
      println(s"$cause")
    }
  }
}
```

2)

```
// define f
def f(x: Try[Message[_]]) = x match {
  case Success(result) => {
    println("The handler un-registration has reached all nodes")
  }
  case Failure(cause) => {
    println(s"$cause")
  }
}

// and later use it
vertx.eventBus.sendFuture("anAddress", "message 1").onComplete(f)
```

=== LITTLE EDIT TO ADD SIMPLE EXPLANATION ==

Have a look at the attached image:

[image]

The code in red is actually the body of a function that does not have a name (anonymous) for which the compiler needs to know the signature (its parameters and the type of them).

So doing `.onComplete { ...` or `.onComplete(f)` is the same but if you define `f` elsewhere you've already defined its signature. If not, you need to do it like this `.onComplete { x: Try[Message[_]] => ...`.

(Little reminder: in Scala you can define functions like this `val double = (i: Int) => { i * 2 }`)